# Statistics of logstash memory consumption

Tags: logstash

I want to install it on a really small server and I want to see if it will be capable of running it with some dignity. So, does anyone have any memory and CPU consumption statistics of running logstash? I understand it depends a lot on the usage, but a reference on the usage could be helpful as well.

Comment: There is no general reference. You need to do your own capacity planning with your expected load, on your desired hardware. Any other information is useless to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @EEAA stated, you need to do your own capacity planning.  It will vary based on the version used, the OS and hardware it's running on, how it's configured, and how much it is used.

However, just to throw it out there:

I'm running Logstash on a CentOS 6 VM using Open JDK 1.7.  The VM has two vCPUs (Xeon E5-2630) and 1 GB of RAM. It sees ~1% CPU utilisaiton with ~128 MB of memory on average used.

Messages are written locally (file) and sent to a graylog2 server using GELF. The configuration is simple, I only have seven `grep` directives.

It's only processing messages from ~150 sources (VM hosts and switches), which amounts to less than 1 message per second.